# Hide/show some part of a table cell jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table as follows:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First (some-text-initially-hidden) click | row |

which on "click" becomes

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First (some-text-should-be visible now) click | row |

on "click" the text "some-text-initially-hidden" is not getting displayed after "click", i want to show and hide the text on "click"
I have a working table as seen here:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aayanarora/16uswof0/2/)

Code:
HTML:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="font-size: 13px;"> 

<th> header1</th>
<th> header2 </th>

<tbody>
   <tr class="test">
        <td>data-always-visible
            <span class="complete">some-data-to hide and show</span>
            <br>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="font-size: 9px;">Click for more details of </i>
        </td>
        <td> some data...</td>
   </tr>
  
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.test~ .test2{
  display: none;
}
.open .test~ .test2{
  display: table-row;
}
.test {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.complete{
    display:none;
}
```

JS/JQuery:

```
        $('table').on('click', 'tr.test .fa-chevron-down', function()         {
            $(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('open');
            $(this).closest('complete').show();
        });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you intend for `.test2` to only appear after a click, or do you want it to be always visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using wrong selector, it should be `.complete` and should use `siblings` instead of `closest`.

```
$(this).siblings('.complete').show();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/dbc349gm/6/

I updated code to show/hide your div

```
 if(!$(this).siblings('.complete').is(":visible")){
  $(this).siblings('.complete').show();
  }else{
  $(this).siblings('.complete').hide();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Hien!!! But i want to toggle the text, but i want to toggle the text, show and hide the text on click.

Comment: I updated code and jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

`span.complete` is a sibling of `i.fa-chevron-down`. `$.closest` only searches the supplied elements themselves and their ancestors.

You can use `$.siblings` instead.

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr.test .fa-chevron-down', function()         {
    $(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('open');
    $(this).siblings('.complete').show();
});
```

```css
.test~ .test2{
  display: none;
}
.open .test~ .test2{
  display: table-row;
}
.test {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.complete{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="font-size: 13px;">

  <th> header1</th>
  <th> header2 </th>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="test">
      <td>data-always-visible
        <span class="complete">some-data-to hide and show</span>
        <br>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="font-size: 9px;">Click for more details of </i>
      </td>
      <td> some data...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="test2">
      <td>data-always-visible</td>
      <td> some data...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test2">
      <td>data-always-visible</td>
      <td> some data...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks David, I have tried it, but it is also not working.

Comment: Check my edit. I've included your code as a snippet and it is working as expected.

Comment: Dang, it is working in your case and not working in my fiddle. Thank you!
but i want to toggle the text, show and hide the text on click.